# Build error, dependency in target requires explicit declaration

Tags: swift, xcode, mesh-network

I used SPM to add  packages to my project/App.  In the package file
I wanted to set target to a dependency. I get this error anytime the app tries to build.

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.5
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Sycra",
    products: [
      
        .library(
            name: "Sycra",
            targets: ["Sycra"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/IOS-nRF-Mesh-Library", .upToNextMinor(from: "3.2.0"))
        
    ],
    targets: [
         define a module or a test suite.
         
        .target(
            name: "Sycra",
            dependencies: ["NordicMesh"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "SycraTests",
            dependencies: ["Sycra"]),
    ]
)
```

**FILE STRUCTURE**

[image: FILE STRUCTURE IMG]

**ERORR**

```
dependency 'NordicMesh' in target 'Sycra' requires explicit declaration; reference the package in the target dependency with '.product(name: "NordicMesh", package: "IOS-nRF-Mesh-Library")'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually the error message already tells you what you have to do:

add

```
.product(name: "NordicMesh", package: "IOS-nRF-Mesh-Library")
```

to the dependencies array:

```
    ... dependencies: [
        .product(name: "NordicMesh", package: "IOS-nRF-Mesh-Library") //<<< like this
        //other dependencies
    ]),
```

Comment: But why is this needed?

Comment: @WizardofKneup You add a dependency to the Package by using `.package(url: ...` to declare other Packages on which dependencies this Package depends on but if you don't add the `.product(name: ...` line within the targets dependencies array, the target doesn't have access to the dependency.